# Passing parameter to crystal report at runtime not working

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I have been trying to resolve this all day but couldn't make it work. I have a crystal report that I want to pass parameter at runtime but still keep on prompting for parameters. Below is my code:

```
 public void LoadReport()
    {
        string studenNo = "A170034511";
        ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
        string reportName = "StdReport";
        cryRpt.Load(Server.MapPath("~/crystalRpts/" + reportName + ".rpt"));

        ParameterFields parameterFields = new ParameterFields();

        //First Parameter
        var parameterField1 = new ParameterField();
        var parameterDiscreteValue1 = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
        parameterField1.ParameterFieldName = "StudentNo";
        parameterDiscreteValue1.Value = studenNo;
        parameterField1.CurrentValues.Add(parameterDiscreteValue1);
        parameterFields.Add(parameterField1);


        //second Parameter
        var parameterField2 = new ParameterField();
        var parameterDiscreteValue2 = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
        parameterField2.ParameterFieldName = "Year";
        parameterDiscreteValue2.Value = "2017";
        parameterField2.CurrentValues.Add(parameterDiscreteValue2);
        parameterFields.Add(parameterField2);


        rptViewer.ParameterFieldInfo = parameterFields;

        rptViewer.ReportSource = cryRpt;
        rptViewer.RefreshReport();

    }
```

With these the parameter window still keep showing. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: Do parameters have same name in Crystal Report too?

Answer (score 0):

I have searched everywhere for the solution to my problem but with no help. After a lots of tries I was able to resolve the issue. Here are my findings:

1. Do not call CrystalReportViewer.RefreshReport(). This refreshes the report and caused the report to clear all the parameters already passed.
2. Call CrystalReport.Refresh() after loading the report
3. Add parameters after setting the CrystalReportViewer report source.

Below is the final code that worked for my whole project with more than 100 reports:

```
public void LoadReport()
{
    string studenNo = "A170034511";
    ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
    string reportName = "StdReport";
    cryRpt.Load(Server.MapPath("~/crystalRpts/" + reportName + ".rpt"));

    cryRpt.Refresh();
    rptViewer.ReportSource = cryRpt;

    ParameterFields parameterFields = new ParameterFields();

    //First Parameter
    var parameterField1 = new ParameterField();
    var parameterDiscreteValue1 = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
    parameterField1.ParameterFieldName = "StudentNo";
    parameterDiscreteValue1.Value = studenNo;
    parameterField1.CurrentValues.Add(parameterDiscreteValue1);
    parameterFields.Add(parameterField1);


    //second Parameter
    var parameterField2 = new ParameterField();
    var parameterDiscreteValue2 = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
    parameterField2.ParameterFieldName = "Year";
    parameterDiscreteValue2.Value = "2017";
    parameterField2.CurrentValues.Add(parameterDiscreteValue2);
    parameterFields.Add(parameterField2);

    rptViewer.ParameterFieldInfo = parameterFields;

    rptViewer.HasCrystalLogo = false;
    rptViewer.Zoom(100);        

}
```

I hope this will help a lot of people having the same issue as mine. Remember to vote as answer if it helps you.